# Display Foreign Field in Combo Box

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox

My database is based on a cinema and features the following tables:

- Movies
- Customers
- Ticket Information
- Screenings
- Bookings

I have created a combo box in the *Bookings* table for the *Screening ID* field:

[image: Text]

This allows me to see a list of information about the cinema's screenings. The four columns that can be seen in this combo box are:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------
| Screening ID        | Screening Date   | Screening Time      | Movie ID
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------
|                     |                  |                     |
```

All of these fields - *Screening ID*, *Screening Date*, *Screening Time* and *Movie ID* - are fetched from the *Screenings* table. But, the final column, *Movie ID*, doesn't really do much for me. I would really like the movie name to be displayed here, as well as just the identifier, but no such field exists in the *Screenings* table. It does exist, however in the *Movies* table, see below:

[image: Text]

(The *Movies* field *Movie ID* is referenced as a foreign key by *Screenings*.)

Is there any way in which I can display this field, *Movie*, as well as *Movie ID* in my combo box from the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `comboBox` RowSource is currently set to `Screenings`

Make a new query that joins screenings and movies and assign the query as the rowSource to your combobox. Something like

```
Select  
    [Screening ID], 
    [Screening Date],
    [Screening Time],
    Movie
From 
screenings inner join movies on screenings.[movie id] = movies.[movie id]
```